# What is the meaning of comments.score?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I don't understand here [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) the meaning of comments.score. Because I don't see any comment that has a score. So this means it is trivial field?

Comment: Look on the left of this comment. It's the number of upvotes and it's called score. For comments without upvotes, it's score is 0 and is not displayed.

Comment: @AndrewT. Actually it's NULL until it gets incremented for the first time. ;)

Comment: @animuson And it's not null anymore even though I un-upvoted it. :P

Comment: How to upvote the comment?

Comment: On the left, on rollover, you have a top arrow (click to upvote) and a flag (to flag this comment as spam, offensive or unconstructive).

Comment: @Fllo: where's the spam option?

Comment: @Filo Invisible to low-reps.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy the little flag below the arrow display a popup with options (as *rude or offensive*,*not constructive*,*obsolete*,*too chatty* and *other*). I think you can add a comment to say you find that as a "spam".

Comment: @Fllo: I know there's a popup, just wondered what you meant by the "spam" option. :)

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Oh sorry (I meant a comment actually) :) - however, it's not from me, the title of the flag on rollover it's "flag this comment as unconstructive, offensive, or spam"

Comment: Related: [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677/168244)

Comment: You can't upvote a comment because you can't upvote anything *yet*. Earn 15 reputation somewhere, look for  a comment and have fun!

Comment: @Qantas It's the same for every site. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: @bjb568: I thought it was when you were able to comment, my bad.

Answer (score 11):

It is the number of upvotes (if any) that the comment got. Most comments don't get any, so you'd see nothing in that field for them.

Answer (score 9):

In this screenshot I indicated what Comments.Score is:

[image]

And you can verify with [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1268860) that the results match.

There are a lot of comments and there are also a heck of a lot of comments with no score. I've [created this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1268804) with three result sets, one which produces a graph, because a picture says more than a thousands words. It shows on the x-axis the score and on the y-xis the Log10 of the count for that score, as well as the length and # days in the same scale.

[image: 3 series: count, length and days. score is on the x-axis, LOG10 on the Y-axis. 3 lines all are high (8 -10) at 0 score and drop quickly to 1-4 for a score of 200. Longtail ends at 1400]

The second and third result set return the oldest zero-scored comment

> [That's true. `serialize()` can be pretty useful for that as well. I think the trick to coming up with a viable system is finding some way to index the data nodes without killing yourself with complexity.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/96035842)

and the highest scored comment:

> [I google this every time. Related comic: https://xkcd.com/1168/](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/30146633)

(all on Stack Overflow)

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the neat [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the awesome [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).